# Azure Artifacts - Need to Create Organization-scoped Feeds

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-artifacts

Devops folks,

I am trying to migrate binaries/packages[full stack .net solution] from myget.org over to azure artefacts and cant find the option to have a common feed.
The scope of this feed is not limited to just one project but across the organization via Azure Active Directory.

The purpose of this common feed is to be used for packaging for all subprojects.

Didn't find any concrete answer, but have been following some developer community post.

Please suggest. thanks

Answer (score 2):

As soon as a DevOps organization is created, an organization scoped feed is already created. Any additional feeds are added as project scoped.

[image]

Another option seems to be by using the [Azure DevOps Api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/artifacts/feed%20%20management/create%20feed?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) and omitting the project parameter.